# How to alter foreignkey with Alembic

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, alembic

I handle my PostgreSQL migrations with `Alembic`. This is how I create a table `items`:

```
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa

def upgrade():
    items_table = op.create_table(
        "items",
        sa.Column("id", UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True),
        sa.Column("user_id", UUID(as_uuid=True), nullable=False),
        sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint("id"),
        sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(
            ["user_id"],
            ["users.id"],
        ),
    )
```

I'd like to make a new migration file to add `ondelete="CASCADE"` after the `sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(...)`. How can I do this using `sqlalchemy`? How do I drop the `ForeignKeyConstraint` and create a new one? Or do I need to drop the whole table and create it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's something that alembic can actually autogenerate, it would drop current constraint and create a new one.
I have a pretty simple model in [this repository](https://gitlab.com/ThirVondukr/fastapi-cookiecutter/-/blob/0a9d834dc6757d74cbccb492e3fd1610a40263d2/src/db/models/book.py)

We can add a self referential relationship as an example:

```py
parent_id: Mapped[int] = Column(ForeignKey("book.id"))
```

```py
def upgrade() -> None:
    op.add_column("book", sa.Column("parent_id", sa.Integer(), nullable=True))
    op.create_foreign_key(
        op.f("fk_book_parent_id_book"), "book", "book", ["parent_id"], ["id"]
    )


def downgrade() -> None:
    op.drop_constraint(op.f("fk_book_parent_id_book"), "book", type_="foreignkey")
    op.drop_column("book", "parent_id")
```

If we add `ondelete="CASCADE"` to it alembic would create new constraint and drop the old one:

```py
parent_id: Mapped[int] = Column(ForeignKey("book.id", ondelete="CASCADE"))
```

```py
def upgrade() -> None:
    op.drop_constraint("fk_book_parent_id_book", "book", type_="foreignkey")
    op.create_foreign_key(
        op.f("fk_book_parent_id_book"),
        "book",
        "book",
        ["parent_id"],
        ["id"],
        ondelete="CASCADE",
    )


def downgrade() -> None:
    op.drop_constraint(op.f("fk_book_parent_id_book"), "book", type_="foreignkey")
    op.create_foreign_key(
        "fk_book_parent_id_book", "book", "book", ["parent_id"], ["id"]
    )
```

You may need to add

```
compare_type=True,
compare_server_default=True,
```

to your `context.configure` call in `alembic/env.py`, it's covered in [alembic documentation](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/autogenerate.html#comparing-types)